# jQuery can't remove class from material bootstrap

Tags: jquery, mdbootstrap

I'm using material bootstrap. And trying to remove `waves-effect waves-light` classes. But it does not work:

```
$("nav a").removeClass("waves-effect waves-light");
```

While if I do add class;

```
$("nav a").addClass("testing"); // it works!
```

It works if use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $("nav a").removeClass("waves-effect waves-light");
},100)
```

But I'm not sure why is this required? I have added script after mdb script.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/site/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/site/js/popper.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/site/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/site/js/mdb.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/site/js/custom-script.js'></script>
```

Comment: Add your `html`

Comment: It's very simple. `a` tag is inside `nav` tag and those classes are added by mdb.

Comment: This should work fine, there is no problem with this code - But I guess you are trying to remove class before `mdb` add!

Comment: Yes, it's a solution! but maybe a little buggy!

Comment: Given that the setTimeout version works, would have to guess that it's a matter of which event thread the jQuery expression runs in. As it stands (without the timeout), the element(s) and/or those class names probably don't exist at the time the expression is executed.

Answer (score 0):

`addClass` work because you trying to add a new `class` to element, but `removeClass` not, because `waves-effect waves-light` class add after you. As you edited your question, you used `setTimeOut` but it's not a stable solution, you are using a library *mdb*, it can load after `100`ms, or even after `1000`, you should use `setInterval` and clear when it removed like below example, this is a safe solution, but I rather to remove this class from source code.

```js
var rm = setInterval(remover, 100);

function remover() {
  $("nav a").removeClass("waves-effect waves-light");
}

function StopInterval() {
  if (!$("nav a").hasClass('.waves-effect.waves-light')) {
    clearInterval(rm);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light">Blah</a>
</nav>
```